# How do I go back to the top of the code?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I have been learning C# and I am creating an app.

I have tried goto statements however the labels are "out of range" I want it to send me back to the original layout which I found out I need to go back to the top of the code.

```
            namespace TheAppOfJack
            {
            [Activity(Label = "The App Of Jack", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
            public class MainActivity : Activity
            {

            int count = 1;

            protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
            {

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            Button button1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
            button1.Click += delegate { button1.Text = string.Format("You have clicked this random button {0} times ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)", count++); };

            Button button2 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
            button2.Click += delegate
            {
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Gallery);
            Button button3 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.back);
            button3.Click += delegate { SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main); };

            Button button4 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.next1);
            button4.Click += delegate
            {
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Gallery2);
            button3.Click += delegate { SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main); };
            Button button5 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.next2);
            button5.Click += delegate
            {

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Gallery3);
            Button button6 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.home);
            button6.Click += delegate {

            //this is where i want the code to send me back to the top };
            };
            };
            };
            }
            }
            }
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? (i.e. why do you want to go back to the top?) Will a `for` loop do what you need?

Comment: I need to get to the top of the code because if i just set it back to the mail layout none of the buton code will work. if this can be solved with a for loop, can you put it into my code as ive never used them and wouldnt know where to start. thx

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is very much antithetical to Android architecture. I think you should find sample projects similar to what you want to do and study them.

Comment: I'm confused as I don't get what are you trying to do? Can you tell me in plain English (forget the code) what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want a button which takes me to a new loyout, from there 2 more buttons(1 to take me back, 1 to go to the next page,from there 2 more buttons(1 to take me home, 1 to go to the next page, then another button to take me to the main layout. when i do this it load the main loyout but ignores all the code for the button therefor making me have to reload the app. taking me to the top of the code would fix it but i dont know the code on how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are trying is not how Android works. You cannot navigate between 'layouts', instead you navigate between activities which have a layout associated with them. This navigation is done using the `StartActivity()` method.

The `MainActivity` is the first activity that will be shown when your app launches. It's associated layout (which is named as `Main` here) should have only one button that will take you to the next screen. Suppose its ID is `btnForActivity2`. Your `OnCreate` for `MainActivity` will be like this:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    Button btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnForActivity2);
    btn.Click += delegate
    {
        StartActivity (typeof(MyActivity2));
    };
}
```

In the `MyActivity2` class, let's say you want to have two buttons to take you to two new activities. Assume one activity is called `MyActivity3` and the other is called `MyActivity4`. In this case, the `OnCreate` method of your `MyActivity2` will be something like this:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MyActivity2Layout);

    Button btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnForActivity3);
    btn.Click += delegate
    {
        StartActivity (typeof(MyActivity3));
    };

    btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnForActivity4);
    btn.Click += delegate
    {
        StartActivity (typeof(MyActivity4));
    };
}
```

This is how basic navigation works in Android.

By the way, you may have noticed that I have not talked about a Back button. It's because I have never explicitly implemented it as, unlike iOS devices, Android devices have a button specifically for that purpose. However, if you must have a button that takes you back to the previous activity then simply calling `this.Finish();` should suffice. Once you call `Finish()` for an activity, it is removed from the top of the activities stack and the activity below becomes visible.

Comment: Thx, this helped loads. I feel like there is a lake of sites showing the basics of this.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Perhaps you can start from here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android_multiscreen/